# How to find out if the input number is balanced?

Tags: c++, loops

According to my lecturer a balanced number is balanced if the sum of its divisors is equal to it self. for example: 6 is a balanced number because 1+2+3=6

These are my very first homework so i am struggeling.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    if (num % (num-1) == 0 ){

    for(int i =1; sum == 0; i++) {
        sum += (num - i);

    }

    if (sum == num) {
        cout << "Great Success" << endl;
        }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong number" << endl;
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: Concentrate on determining the divisors first, by writing a program that prints the divisors of a number. Add the summation only after you're sure that your divisor-determining program works.

Comment: Start with indenting your code.

Comment: what is your question? Do you know how to find all divisors of a number with pen and paper? What is with your code? You check only if the input number `num` is divisible by `num-1` but you need to find all divisors (btw `num-1` is never a divisor of `num`)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a coding question, but a "how do I design this algorithm" question. That is off-topic here. Once you have a working algorithm, but struggle to translate it into code, that might be on-topic. (If you have a working algorithm, then please update your question describing it, and clarify where and how you struggle implementing it in code.) See [Where should I post questions about algorithms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin)

Comment: `(num % (num-1) == 0 ` is only true for `num == 2` or `num == 0`. It's a division by 0 for `num == 1`.

Comment: I believe the main reason for your struggling is that you started to write a program before solving the problem, possibly even before understanding what the problem is. This is not wrong - sometimes it's an excellent way of figuring out what you haven't figured out yet - but you also need to take a step back and think some more. And don't be afraid of admitting defeat and starting over.

Comment: @MaxVollmer the accepted answer of the Q you link says "If you implement algorithms as part of the course, then questions about the coding part should be asked on Stack Overflow". Questions about algorithms are not offtopic on SO per se

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes, about the coding part. But as I wrote, to me this feels more about the algorithm and less about the coding part. I specifically suggested OP to update the question with the algorithm in case I got that wrong.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I frequently see questions with the `algorithm` tag on SO that are not about code but the algorithm. Maybe you are right, but this is the first time I hear that such question would be offtopic on SO

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I mean, I might very well be wrong! No close votes cast and your answer is well received.

Answer (score 4):

Do the maths first. Often code being a bit messy is just a consequence of not preparing yourself good enough to write the code. Dont start writing code before you know what you want to write. Frankly, from your code one can see that it is something related to `num-1` dividing `num`, but otherwise it is not clear how it is supposed to solve the problem. And its intendation makes it quite hard to read, so lets forget about the code and start from scratch...

`y` is a divisor of `x` exactly if `x % y == 0`. The biggest possible divisor of `x` is `x/2`. To get all divisors we can simply check every number from `2` up to `x/2` (`1` is always considered a divisor, hence no need to check).

Only now we can write some code:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
int sum = 1;
for (int y = 2; y <= x/2; ++y){
    if ( check_if_y_is_divisor) { sum += y; }
}
bool is_balanced = sum == x;
```

I left a tiny hole in the code that you have to fill (I just dont like to give away the full solution when it is homework).